# Which method is better or would work when trying to save gestures?

Tags: android, storage, gesture

Currently, i'm making an application that involves using `GestureOverlayView`. I've already created some default gestures using the `GestureBuilder` and have copied them into my `res/raw` folder in my application. My application also does customization, meaning that the user can create his or her own gestures and save them. I've read that it's impossible for me to just save the additionally made gestures from the users to the `res/raw` folder. I was told that i have some optionals: `ExternalStorage` (to SD card), `InternalStorage`, and `SharedPreferences`. Which method is probably the more optimal choice?

This is what i have so far:

```
package com.epicunlock.rx24race;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.gesture.GestureLibraries;
import android.gesture.GestureLibrary;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener;
import android.gesture.Prediction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

//Default gestures: s, d, b, c
public class createShortcut extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener {

EditText scName;
private GestureLibrary gestureLib;
FileOutputStream fos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.createshortcutlayout);
    scName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView)findViewById(R.id.gestures);
    gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
    gestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
    if (!gestureLib.load()) {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestureLib.recognize(gesture);
    if (predictions.size() > 0) {
        Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);
        if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            gestureLib.addGesture(scName.getText().toString(), gesture);
            gestureLib.save();
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Update: my current code saves the gestures, but they're unsaved when i exit the application

Comment: Can anyone else help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is a gesture builder sample in the sdk samples.  samples/android-17/GestureBuilder.

This sample shows how to create, save etc gestures.

For the short answer to your question in the sample they use the addgesture() and save() methods to save the gestures to the gesture library.

Comment: I've tried the addgesture() and save() methods, but they didn't work. Sure it saves it, but when i exit out of the application and start it again, it's not there anymore.